# How to retrain a detection model and quantize it for Intel Movidius?

Tags: python, movidius, quantization-aware-training

I want to retrain an existing object detection model with a new image dataset and quantize it for Intel Movidius. Is there any working procedure to do this?

I have successfully retrained the model but failing to quantize it. I have followed the following tutorial [Retrain SSD MobileNet](https://tolotra.com/2018/09/15/how-to-retrain-ssd-mobilenet-for-real-time-object-detection-using-a-raspberry-pi-and-movidius-neural-compute-stick/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Movidius devices only support FP16 models, and to convert a caffe version of SSD Mobilenet then you supply the "--data_type FP16"to the model optimizer (mo.py)
The openvino model zoo has a mobilenet-ssd model,also using caffe, and the associated yaml file has the following parameters
model_optimizer_args:

- --input_shape=[1,3,300,300]
- --input=data
- --mean_values=data[127.5,127.5,127.5]
- --scale_values=data[127.5]
- --output=detection_out
- --input_model=$dl_dir/mobilenet-ssd.caffemodel
- --input_proto=$dl_dir/mobilenet-ssd.prototxt.

Note that your input shape and the mean and scale values will likely be different so change those to match your retrained model.

There's also a demo file shipped with [openvino](/questions/tagged/openvino) that can be used with your converted model. See the associated mode.lst file for all the supported architectures. https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/object_detection_demo/python